# Не устанавливается Microsoft Visial Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, sdk

Пытаюсь установить MSVS 2017. На этапе установки SDK установщик начинает требовать какие-то пакеты. Хотя у меня все пакеты закачены. И не понятно, почему запрашивается пакет из папки Win81_SDK, если ставится Win10SDK.

Моя ОС - WIN 7 SP 1 64

Как мне установить MSVS 2017 корректно?

[image: Ошибка установки]

Comment: скорее всего конфликтует как раз тот момент что у тебя уже стоят пакеты. Ты их либо удали либо найди где они у тебя в системе прописаны и удали от туда(path). Ну и почему вы ставите версию enterprise? вам community нужно ставить.

Comment: Я и community пробовал, и PRO - результат не меняется. Установка останавливается на одном и том же месте.

Comment: Видно что есть конфликты. Посмотрите свой path может вы в одно и тоже место назначили пути для разных версий и при установке вы пытается положить файлы с одинаковыми названиями. Попробовал только что налить vs17 на чистую машину все получилось.